# npm run build missing files - vitejs

Tags: npm, bundler, github-pages, netlify, vite

When using Netlify to host my static website, I need to run `npm run build` to be able to publish it.

However, when I am doing the process the folder that is being made after I run the command is missing a huge amount of data and thus my website is barely functional. What is going on?

My code is here: https://github.com/aymhh/vChat

I tried to use GitHub pages however errors like these keep coming up and I do not know what to do to fix them [image]

I just would like to be able to use this in the same way I use localhost but for others to be able to access it. I don't mind either platform to host my static site.

What can I do now to be able to host my website for free?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [`actions/github-pages-action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-pages-action) in order to build your site.

It would build and deploy the site on the `gh-pages` branch by default, which means your GitHub (`http://username.github.io/repository`, in your case: https://aymhh.github.io/vChat/) would be rendered from the content of that branch, provided you did [configure your publishing source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) accordingly.